# Regular expression to find the first occurrence of string from a point of another string

Tags: regex

My text is

```
 < <footnotes><footnote><info><![CDATA[Some text ‘ ”https://www.google.com”> AAAA OR    ” https://www.google.com”> AAAA OR    ” https://www.google.com”> AAAA OR   ” https://www.google.com”> AAAA’]]></info></footnote></footnotes><resources></resources>
```

I need to find the text from the first `"https"` till `"]]"`, and I was able to do it like:

```
(?=https).*?(?=\]\])
```

But what if I have to find the `"info"` text from there find the first `"https"` till `"]]"`?

And is there a way to remove any character between the text? If suppose I am getting the text between `"https"` to `"]]"` and I have to remove all the `"OR"` from my result string?

So my final result from regex will look like

```
https://www.google.com”> AAAA     ” https://www.google.com”> AAAA     ” https://www.google.com”> AAAA    ” https://www.google.com”> AAAA’
```

How to do it with the single regex?

Comment: Your expected output does not even match what is inside the `<info>` tag.  Can you clarify how you arrive your expected output?

Comment: I was not to find the result just by using "https" as my first text and "]]"
But I was not able to do it using info. Thats why I asked the question.
Could u please help me out

Comment: What tool/language are you using here?  I think trying to craft a regex to do nitty-gritty cleanup in a string would be a potential headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when parsing nested content like XML or HTML, one should use a proper parser, and not a single regex.  That being said, the following pattern seems to work, at least for the sample data you showed us given the requirements:

```
<info>.*?(https.*)\]\]
```

The text captured from the above are the Google URLs appearing after the `<info>` tag and before the double closing brackets of the CDATA clause.

### Demo

Comment: Thanks Tim. Is there a way to remove any unwanted string or a number of unwanted strings of the result
Is that can be done using the same regex ?

Comment: This is precisely what my above questions were trying to ask you.  I can't give you an answer for that, without knowing exactly what you want to do.  But I would say that cleaning up the text you extracted might be best done in the language you are using to call the regex (e.g. Java, Perl, C#, etc.).